# Authentication in stateless API service - is it secure?

Tags: rest, authentication, cryptography, digital-signature, stateless

Are there any standard practices for dealing with stateless authentication?

I am creating an API server and would like for each request to be signed by the client, in such a way that I can guarantee that the issuer of the request is a valid user of our site.

Server and client have a shared secret - i.e. the hashed password of the user, so...

- Server sends a random nonce value to the client
- Client constructs a signing key K as (nonce,hashed_password)
- Client 'signs' each request by appending a message authentication code using key K

  - e.g. ('delete image_x',user_id,request_signature)
- Server then checks the signature as being valid for every request before processing it.

Are there any obvious flaws?

Comment: Is `hashed_password` is being sent over internet or simply known by both server and client? In second case you can use MAC (message authentication code). Using of digital signature is unreasonable.

Comment: Thats probably what I meant actually, oops.

Comment: So, it is almost secure.

Answer (score 0):

Look at what they use for the Amazon Web Services, they do all of this.